# Returning variables from a custom view to a activity which called it

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

Hello I am new to android. 
I am calling a custom view from main activity and i want to return some variables from the custom view to that activity. So how can i do that.
This is my code for transferring the control to that custom view.
`setContentView(new myView(this, rotatedBitmap));`
Now from this custom view i want to return to that same main activity and return same variable as well.

Comment: can't you use getter and setters??

Comment: i am calling this customView and now the entire control is in this view how can i use getter and setters to get values processed in this view to be used in that activity?

Comment: you can you the instance of view and call getter and setter. Just look at some customview you will get the idea

Comment: can you please give me some reference or code to refer to